# Smoothing a unit step function

Tags: differential-equations, functions

I want to smooth a unit step function for use in `NDSolve` so this function is a smooth function of time (`t`). How can I do the smoothing? The unit step function is defined by:

```
α = π/6;
Vbusd[t_] := 5 (1 - Exp[-t]);
Vbusq[t_] := 3 Exp[-t];

n = UnitStep[Vbusd[t]*Cos[t - α - π/6] - Vbusq[t]*Sin[t - α - π/6]]  -
    UnitStep[Vbusd[t]*Cos[t - α - (5 π)/6] - Vbusq[t]*Sin[t - α - (5 π)/6]];
```

Comment: After a second look I think your question is a little unclear. What do you really want? Smoothen `n` with `NDSolve` or find a smooth approximation of `n` which is to be used in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Thanks alot for help. finding a smooth approximation of n which is to be used in NDSolve.

Comment: I normally use `Tanh`

Answer (score 4):

These are the transitions I usually use: (both are $C^{\infty}$)

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{(Erf[Sqrt[2 π] ArcTanh[x]] + 1)/2, -1 < x < 1}}, UnitStep[x]]
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{(Tanh[Sqrt[2] Tan[π/2 x]] + 1)/2, -1 < x < 1}}, UnitStep[x]]

Plot[{UnitStep[x], f[x], g[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Picture]

Comment: Could you please post text (code-styled markdown) that can be cut and pasted rather than images of your code? This makes it easy for people to grab your solution and experiment with it.

Comment: But I do not know time of rising and falling levels for difinition of unitstep and Tanh !